# Export Grouped Rows from Data table

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I made a Datatable with Grouped Rows. And using Export option in the table.
However, on exporting the data grouped rows are not getting exported to excel. Only original rows are getting printed. Is there a way we can print grouped rows?
Code I'm using is:

```
exportOptions:{
    rows: {'.dtrg-group'},
    columns:{0,1,2}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Datatables How to print a table with row grouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328708/jquery-datatables-how-to-print-a-table-with-row-grouping)